# How to show empty message in table data (td) if ng.for is less than table headers (th)?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have this code to show data in a table. I only have 3 car and 3 bike when iterating, How can I show an empty message for table datas (td) in table headers (th) #4 and #5?

I would like to find a dynamic solution. So, if I had less cars or bikes still show the empty message or if I have them all, show no empty message.

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-ranking text-center">
    <thead class="thead-light">
        <tr>
            <th class="no-bg"></th>
            <th>#1</th>
            <th>#2</th>
            <th>#3</th>
            <th>#4</th>
            <th>#5</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="thead-light">
        <tr>
            <th>Car</th>
            <td *ngFor="let car of ranking?.totals?.car">
                {{ car?.property?.name }}<br /><span
                    class="muted small">{{ car?.total / millionDivisor | number: '1.0-2' }} MM EUR
                    | {{ car?.percentage | number: '1.0-2' }}%</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Bike</th>
            <td *ngFor="let bike of ranking?.totals?.bike">
                {{ bike?.property?.name }}<br /><span
                    class="muted small">{{ bike?.total / millionDivisor | number: '1.0-2' }} MM EUR
                    | {{ bike?.percentage | number: '1.0-2' }}%</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Sample data

````
 ranking:{
 "totals": {
            "car": [
                {
                    "property": {
                        "_id": "5f8ffa5e4106274",
                        "name": "porsche",
                        "hash": "aCTGdtRUhy",
                        "createdAt": "2020-10-21T09:07:42.524Z",
                        "updatedAt": "2021-02-01T09:59:01.571Z",
                        "__v": 0
                    },
                    "total": 89687422,
                    "percentage": 99.99993756096029,
                    "ranking": 1
                },
                {
                    "property": {
                        "_id": "5fe413938125ad06272",
                        "name": "seat",
                        "hash": "UOMTGBb5L",
                        "createdAt": "2020-10-21T09:07:42.425Z",
                        "updatedAt": "2021-02-01T09:59:01.529Z",
                        "__v": 0
                    },
                    "total": 56,
                    "percentage": 0.00006243903970630104,
                    "ranking": 2
                },
                {
                    "property": {
                        "_id": "6069e612f1686a672c201",
                        "name": "mercedes",
                        "hash": "aCTGhh",
                        "createdAt": "2020-10-21T09:07:42.524Z",
                        "updatedAt": "2021-02-01T09:59:01.571Z",
                        "__v": 0
                    },
                    "total": 0,
                    "percentage": 0,
                    "ranking": 3
                }
            ],
            "bike": [
                {
                    "property": {
                        "_id": "5f8ffa5e413938125ad",
                        "name": "A",
                        "hash": "UGBb5L",
                        "createdAt": "2020-10-21T09:07:42.425Z",
                        "updatedAt": "2021-02-01T09:59:01.529Z",
                        "__v": 0
                    },
                    "total": 1286553.2196000002,
                    "percentage": 50.14333136951876,
                    "ranking": 1
                },
                {
                    "property": {
                        "_id": "538125ad06274",
                        "name": "B",
                        "hash": "GdtRUhy",
                        "createdAt": "2020-10-21T09:07:42.524Z",
                        "updatedAt": "2021-02-01T09:59:01.571Z",
                        "__v": 0
                    },
                    "total": 1279198.1664,
                    "percentage": 49.856668630481266,
                    "ranking": 2
                },
                {
                    "property": {
                        "_id": "12f1686a672c201",
                        "name": "C",
                        "hash": "aCRUhh",
                        "createdAt": "2020-10-21T09:07:42.524Z",
                        "updatedAt": "2021-02-01T09:59:01.571Z",
                        "__v": 0
                    },
                    "total": 0,
                    "percentage": 0,
                    "ranking": 3
                }
            ]
        }
}
```
````

Comment: Can you give a sample dataset for ranking?

Comment: @Arcteezy I added the data sample to the post.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something with index and checking if the value is undefined or not.

```html
<td *ngFor="let index of [0,1,2,3,4]">
    <span *ngIf="ranking?.totals?.car[index]">
        {{ ranking?.totals?.car[index]?.property?.name }}<br /><span
            class="muted small">{{ ranking?.totals?.car[index]?.total / millionDivisor | number: '1.0-2' }} MM EUR
            | {{ ranking?.totals?.car[index]?.percentage | number: '1.0-2' }}%</span>
    </span>
    <span *ngIf="ranking?.totals?.car[index]==undefined">
        No data available
    </span>
</td>
```

Demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tc65j9?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: thanks a lot @Arcteezy. This solution works!